# how to distinguish these 2 object in typescript

Tags: typescript, object

I have a question about how to distinguish these 2 object in typescript.

```
oobject1 = {
 names: [{
   firstName: abc,
   lastName: asdf

 },
{
   firstName: trtrtr,
   lastName: sdsdsdf

 },

]

}
```

the second object looks like this:

```
object2 = {
id: 12322,
name: 2323
}

because I got a object, in which there 2 objects are as sub object. 
I write a method, which to build a dynamic form, if object 1, then should this sub form called names, if object 2, should sub form called the other
```

Comment: What do you mean by "distinguish"? TypeScript will infer different types for them, which distinguishes them from one another. What are you trying to do? If you tell us more, we may be able to help you.

Comment: You can checkfor the presence of the `id` attribute, for example. Just `object2` has an `id` attribute.